# How can I find and replace text in Word using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using Excel VBA to open a document in Word. Once the document is open the goal is to search for "InsuranceCompanyName" and replace it with the company's name.

I have tried

```
wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="InsuranceCompanyName", ReplaceWith:="Fake Ins Co"
```

and

```
wordDoc.Replace What:="InsuranceCompanyName", Replacement:="Fake Ins Co"
```

and also

```
For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "InsuranceCompanyName"
        .Replacement.Text = "Fake Ins Co"
        .WrapText = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With 
Next myStoryRange
```

The full code is listed below.

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim wordApp As Object 
Dim wordDoc As Object 
Dim myStoryRange As Range

'sets up the word app
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = True 

'opens the document that we need to search through 
Set wordDoc = wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQdoc.docx")

'here is where the find and replace code would go

End Sub
```

For the first method I get the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

For the second: the same error

The third method:

> argument not optional

in regards to the .Find in

```
With myStoryRange.Find
```

Comment: `Set wordDoc = wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQdoc.docx")` should be `Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQdoc.docx")`

Comment: `ActiveDocument` is not an Excel concept, so you need to preface that with `wordApp`   i.e. `wordApp.ActiveDocument`

Comment: `For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges` Worked for me

Comment: Also ensure that you declare the constants `wdFindContinue`, `wdReplaceAll` etc since you are late binding with MS Word

Comment: ...and finally if you've not added a reference to the word object libary then constants such as `wdFindContinue` will not be recognized by Excel VBA.  If you're using `option Explicit` (as you should *always*) then Excel will warn you, otherwise it will just silently assign a default value.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - snap!

Comment: It won't make it past the .Find before that to run the With section.

Comment: Cass, read up. Ensure you've incorpoarated the above suggestions :)

Comment: I did so. I removed the extra "wordDoc =", I'm using the "wordApp.StoryRanges", and I got rid of "wdFindContinue" . None of those solve the issue with it getting stuck on ".Find". It won't run past that line with the same error I stated in the original problem statement

Comment: Change `Dim myStoryRange As Range` to `Dim myStoryRange As Object`

Comment: When I change it to Object it says that it doesn't support that method for the "For Each myStoryRange In wordApp.StoryRanges"

Comment: I posted an answer. Try it. I tested it an it works

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Const wdReplaceAll = 2

Sub FindReplace()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim myStoryRange As Object

    '~~> Sets up the word app
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Opens the document that we need to search through
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.docx")

    For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges
        With myStoryRange.Find
            .Text = "InsuranceCompanyName"
            .Replacement.Text = "Fake Ins Co"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next myStoryRange
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: This is great! It no longer gets hung up on that line and continues past it. However, it doesn't actually replace the text that it was supposed to find and replace.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. You may have to refresh th epage to see it

Comment: BTW I hope you declared `Const wdReplaceAll = 2` on the top of your code ;)?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the help. Always much appreciated.